# How to integrate AWS Device Farm with TFS build

Tags: tfs, aws-device-farm

I am looking to  integrate AWS Device Farm with my TFS Build. I have an .apk that I want to test on the Device Farm. Is there a TFS Build plugin similar to jenkins, if not then is there an API I can connect to in AWS to upload my apk and get results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default plugin or service to integrate AWS Device Farm with TFS Build. After you get .apk file from TFS build, you need to use AWS Device Farm UI or CLI or API to run the test.

Useful links:

- http://blog.learningtree.com/en/android-user-interface-testing-on-amazons-device-farm-part-2/
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/cli-ref.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html